# How to iterate through a tuple list of lists, and get all elements one by one in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting, tuples

My list like this a big list contains several sublist with different size

```
test_list = [
             [('c1t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')],
             [('c2t1'), ('c2t2'), ('c2t3')],
             [('c3t1'), ('c3t2')],
             [('c4t1'), ('c4t2')],
             [('c5t1')]
                    ]
```

I want to use this list to create a new list like this:

```
new_list = [('c1t1'), ('c2t1'), ('c3t1'), ('c4t1'), ('c5t1'), 
            ('c1t2'), ('c2t2'), ('c3t2'), ('c4t2'), 
            ('c1t3'), ('c2t3'), 
            ('c1t4'), 
            ('c1t5')]
```

with correct order, like each time take first one tuple from sublist append to new list. By "correct order", I mean flattening by column.

Comment: They're not tuples. I can't test just now but I have a feeling those parentheses will disappear as soon as you define the list. It is a comma, not brackets, that creates a tuple

Comment: Source of above comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using itertools.zip_longest

```
test_list = [
         [('c1t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')],
         [('c2t1'), ('c2t2'), ('c2t3')],
         [('c3t1'), ('c3t2')],
         [('c4t1'), ('c4t2')],
         [('c5t1')]
                ]

from itertools import zip_longest     
new_list = [(item,) for my_list in zip_longest(*test_list) for item in my_list if item]
print(new_list)
```

output

```
[('c1t1',), ('c2t1',), ('c3t1',), ('c4t1',), ('c5t1',), ('c1t2',), ('c2t2',), ('
c3t2',), ('c4t2',), ('c1t3',), ('c2t3',), ('c1t4',), ('c1t5',)]
```

or

```
new_list = [item for my_list in zip_longest(*test_list) for item in my_list if item]
```

if desired result is

```
['c1t1', 'c2t1', 'c3t1', 'c4t1', 'c5t1', 'c1t2', 'c2t2', 'c3t2', 'c4t2', 'c1t3',  'c2t3', 'c1t4', 'c1t5']
```

Comment: thanks so much, fit my requirement, no matter what the tuple value in there, the order alway correct

Comment: the desired result is: [('c1t1'), ('c2t1'), ('c3t1'), ('c4t1'), ('c5t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c2t2'), ('c3t2'), ('c4t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c2t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')], but your answer really close it

Comment: if that is what you want, then the second option is what you want. `('c1t1')` is a string, not tuple. I have changed the names in the snippet accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple of functional programming tricks from the `itertools` module:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest, chain
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x, chain(*zip_longest(*test_list))))
['c1t1', 'c2t1', 'c3t1', 'c4t1', 'c5t1', 'c1t2', 'c2t2', 'c3t2', 'c4t2', 'c1t3', 'c2t3', 'c1t4', 'c1t5']
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable(...)` is more efficient than `chain(*...)`, otherwise fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to achieve this, however many nested layers there are.
See below function:

```
def recurflatten(arr):
    if not isinstance(arr, list):
        return arr
    else:
        output = []
        for sy in arr:
            if isinstance(sy, list):
                temp = recurflatten(sy)
                for py in temp:
                    output.append(py)
            else:
                output.append(sy)
        return output

test_list = [
             [('c1t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')],
             [('c2t1'), ('c2t2'), ('c2t3')],
             [('c3t1'), ('c3t2')],
             [('c4t1'), ('c4t2')],
             [('c5t1')]
                    ]

new_list =[]
for x in recurflatten(test_list):
    new_list.append((x,))

print (new_list)
# [('c1t1',), ('c1t2',), ('c1t3',), ('c1t4',), ('c1t5',), ('c2t1',), ('c2t2',), ('c2t3',), ('c3t1',), ('c3t2',), ('c4t1',), ('c4t2',), ('c5t1',)]
```

Edit: If you do not wish to have the tuples, you can run:

```
print(recurflatten(test_list))
# ['c1t1', 'c1t2', 'c1t3', 'c1t4', 'c1t5', 'c2t1', 'c2t2', 'c2t3', 'c3t1', 'c3t2', 'c4t1', 'c4t2', 'c5t1']
```

Comment: @jpp It does, why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Thanks for you quick respond, I want the output list list this: [('c1t1'), ('c2t1'), ('c3t1'), ('c4t1'), ('c5t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c2t2'), ('c3t2'), ('c4t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c2t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')]

Comment: @Jimmy you're welcome, please remember to mark as correct answer if it is what you require

Comment: @jpp Have you seen the initial output from `new_list`?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat complicated, but working (maybe it can be further simplified):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import starmap


def f(i, *args):
    try:
        return args[i]
    except IndexError:
        pass

result = []
for v in (starmap(partial(func, i), test_list) for i in range(0, max([len(l) for l in test_list]))):
    result.extend(n for n in v if n is not None)
```

Output:

```
[('c1t1',), ('c2t1',), ('c3t1',), ('c4t1',), ('c5t1',), ('c1t2',), 'c2t2',), ('c3t2',), ('c4t2',), ('c1t3',), ('c2t3',), ('c1t4',), ('c1t5',)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use List Comprehension:

```
test_list = [
             [('c1t1'), ('c1t2'), ('c1t3'), ('c1t4'), ('c1t5')],
             [('c2t1'), ('c2t2'), ('c2t3')],
             [('c3t1'), ('c3t2')],
             [('c4t1'), ('c4t2')],
             [('c5t1')]
            ] 
new_list = [item for list2 in test_list for item in list2]
```

**Output:**

```
['c1t1', 'c1t2', 'c1t3', 'c1t4', 'c1t5', 'c2t1', 'c2t2', 'c2t3', 'c3t1', 'c3t2', 'c4t1', 'c4t2', 'c5t1']
```